# i am making the ajax call from the html to nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, node.js, express

i am making the ajax call from html to nodejs to retrieve the data from the server,data is returning from the server but in browser it is not displaying

```
//html code
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>      
        <script>
            function changeText1() {
                var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                myRequest.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if(myRequest.status==200 && myRequest.readystate==4) {
                    console.log("successfully received ");
                    var name=JSON.parse(myRequest.responseText);
                    console.log(name);
                    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = name.title;
                } else {
                    console.log("Cannot process");
                }
            }
            myRequest.open("GET","http://localhost:3000/endpoint",true);
            myRequest.send(null);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv">Hello welcome</div>
        <button type="button" onclick="changeText1()">Change Content</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

//server side code(in nodejs)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/"));


app.get('/endpoint', function(req, res) {
    var obj = {};
    obj.title = 'Ajax project';
    //obj.data = 'Welcome';

    res.header('Content-type','application/json');
    res.header('Charset','utf8');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
    res.send(JSON.stringify(obj) );
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Server started");
```

Data is retrieving from the server
but the control is failing to enter

```
if(myRequest.status==200 && myRequest.readystate==4)
```

and displays cannot process

Comment: Do a console.log("Status:" + myRequest.status + "readyState: " +myRequest..readyState) and see what you are getting.

Comment: Unless i overlooked something, you never send your request any where?

Answer (score 1):

readyState is written in camelCasing instead of 'readystate' that's why you can't see a result, 'readystate' is undefined. I strongly suggest you use '===' instead of '==' in your if-statement.

Also I would write this code after you've opened the request.

```
myRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if(myRequest.readyState === 4) {
      if(myRequest.status === 200) { //DO STUFF}
   }
}
```